# What steps can I take to fix an InvalidRequestContent error when substituting variables with FileTransform@1 in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd, azure-bicep

FileTransform@1 fails for variable substitution

I'm trying to substitute the values in the main.parameters.json file to the variable values from my variable group.

The file transform gives a green check and says that the value has been substituted, however the what-if gives an error.

This is the error:

> ERROR: {"error":{"code":"InvalidRequestContent","message":"The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Error converting value "test" to type 'Azure.Deployments.Core.Definitions.DeploymentParameterDefinition'. Path 'properties.parameters.tier', line 1, position 81.'."}}
> ##[error]Script failed with exit code: 1

This is the part of my yaml code:

```
`trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - bicep
 
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
  - group: myGroup
  - name: parameters.tier
    value: "$(tier)"

stages:

- stage: Preview
  jobs:
  - job: PreviewAzureChanges
    displayName: Preview Azure changes
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "Print tier value"
          echo "Value: $(tier)"

    - task: FileTransform@1
      displayName: 'File transformation: main.parameters.json'
      inputs:
        folderPath: 'bicep\'
        targetFiles: 'main.parameters.json'
        fileType: json

    - task: AzureCLI@2
      name: RunWhatIf
      displayName: Run what-if
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(environment)
        scriptType: bash
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          az deployment group what-if \
            --resource-group $(rg) \
            --template-file 'bicep\main.bicep' \
            --parameters 'bicep\main.parameters.json'`
```

This is my main.parameters.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "franchisee": {
      "value": "myFranchisee"
    },
    "tier": {
      "value": "myTier"
    },
    "location": {
      "value": "myLocation"
    },
    "rg": {
      "value": "myRg"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your main bicep file with us or at least how these parameters are defined in your template please ?

Comment: The parameters are defined like this in the main.bicep file:

`param location string
param franchisee string
param tier string
param rg string`

And this is how they are used in the main.bicep file:

`module storage 'modules/storage.bicep' = {
  name: 'storage_deployment_${guid}'
  params: {
    location: location
    franchisee: franchisee
    tier: tier
  }
}`

Comment: can you print out the parameter files after transformation ?

Comment: After printing the parameters file post transformation, I saw where the issue was.
The transformed parameters file looked like this:
`{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "franchisee": {
            "value": myFranchisee
        },
        "tier": "test",
        "location": {
            "value": "myLocation"
        },
        "rg": {
            "value": "myRg"
        }
    }
}`

**This was resolved by changing the name to parameters.tier.value**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to change

```
variables:
  - group: myGroup
  - name: parameters.tier
    value: "$(tier)"
```

to

```
variables:
  - group: myGroup
  - name: parameters.tier.value
    value: "$(tier)"
```